# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, ajax

Pessoal estou tendo este erro na linha 14 do meu script porem não estou conseguindo enxergar o erro, se quem puder ajudar, agradeço!!

linha 14 ->               error:function(data){

todo cód

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function confLojas(id) {
   var resposta = confirm("Deseja realmente remover esse registro?");

   if (resposta == true) {
        $.ajax({
          type:'GET',
          url:'../php/deleteLojas.php',
          data:'id'+id,
          success:function(data){
            alert("Registro exluído com sucesso!");
            $("#"+id).hide();
          }
          error:function(data){ //linha 14
            alert("Erro!");
          }
        });
      }
  }

function confSites(id) {
   var resposta = confirm("Deseja realmente remover esse registro?");

   if (resposta == true) {
     $.ajax({
       type:'GET',
       url:'../php/deleteSites.php',
       data:'id'=id,
       success:function(data){
         alert("Registro exluído com sucesso!");
         $("#"+id).hide();
       }
       error: function(data){
         alert("Erro!");
       }
     });
   }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Falta **a vírgula** antes do `error`, nos dois casos.

```
success:function(data){
    alert("Registro exluído com sucesso!");
    $("#"+id).hide();
},
error:function(data){ //linha 14
    alert("Erro!");
}
```

Comment: Valeu, era isso mesmo! Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Só pra constar: você pode marcar as respostas para suas perguntas como corretas usando o **✓** abaixo das setas para votar. Percebi que você tem uma outra pergunta que não aceitou resposta, então achei bom avisar =D

Comment: Valeu, sou novo e não sabia disso!

Comment: Eu imaginei. Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]

Comment: Valeu jbueno  :D